# How to Customize the Error Response in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is what i want!
I have a view and i want to send the API JWT Token along with request
i want to verify if the token is valid or not
if it is Valid it gives the responce

```
Response({"gpcars": gpSerial.data, "featuredCars": featSerial.data, "recentcars": RecentSerial.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and if its not valid so the user is unauthenticated then this should be the responce

```
Response({"gpcars": gpSerial.data, "featuredCars": featSerial.data, "recentcars": RecentSerial.data}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHENTICATED)
```

Basically i want to determine if the user is logged in or not along with the request.

This is what i have tried

```
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            # Fetch the first 5 Car objects
            GpCars = Car.objects.order_by(
                '-stockid').filter(gpcar=True, featured=False)[:6]
            FeaturedCars = Car.objects.order_by(
                '-stockid').filter(gpcar=False, featured=True)[:6]
            RecentCars = Car.objects.order_by(
                '-stockid').filter(gpcar=False, featured=False)[:6]

            # Serialize the queryset
            gpSerial = CarSerializer(GpCars, many=True)
            featSerial = CarSerializer(FeaturedCars, many=True)
            RecentSerial = CarSerializer(RecentCars, many=True)

            time.sleep(5)
            return Response({"gpcars": gpSerial.data, "featuredCars": featSerial.data, "recentcars": RecentSerial.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle other exceptions as needed
            return Response({"gpcars": gpSerial.data, "featuredCars": featSerial.data, "recentcars": RecentSerial.data}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHENTICATED)
```

Comment: If the user is unauthenticated, do you still want to return the data?

Comment: yes i need to return the same data in both cases just different status code!

Comment: You have to create a function that checks user authentication if you are using an authentication class it will always give 401 not your custom response.
Use that just above when you are retuning response.